# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ')' on line 59

Tags: php, forms, parsing, swiftmailer

I am getting the following errors, trying to setup my webform to use Swift Mailer on GoDaddy's cPanel, Linux hosting service.

What am I doing wrong?

Beginning at line 57, the code (emails hidden) is:

```
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transort);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Web Inquiry')
->setFrom (array('email1@myemail.com' -> 'Web Inquiry'))
->setTo (array('email@email.com' -> 'Inquiry Recipients'))
->setBcc (array('email@email.com' -> 'Inquiry BCC Recipient, respond from email@email.com.net'))
->setSubject (array('Inquiry from email.com'))
->setBody (array($data, 'text/html'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the array you want to use the `=>` operator for pairing keys and values whereas for chaining object methods you are correctly using the `->` operator

```
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transort);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Web Inquiry')
->setFrom (array('email1@myemail.com' => 'Web Inquiry'))
->setTo (array('email@email.com' => 'Inquiry Recipients'))
->setBcc (array('email@email.com' => 'Inquiry BCC Recipient, respond from email@email.com.net'))
->setSubject (array('Inquiry from email.com'))
->setBody (array($data, 'text/html'));
```